# Susy: susy-grid-background always shows 12 columns regardless of $total-cols no

Tags: css, compass-sass, sass, susy-compass

From the Susy docs: http://susy.oddbird.net/guides/reference/#ref-grid-background

> SUSY GRID BACKGROUND
>   Show the Susy Grid as a background-image on any container.
>
> // susy-grid-background();
>   .page { @include susy-grid-background; }
>
> If you are using the  element as your Container, you need to apply a background to the  element in order for this grid-background to size properly.

Snippets of my css:

```
$total-cols     : 16;
$column-width   : 4em;
$gutter-width   : 1em;
$grid-padding   : $gutter-width;

html { background: #fff no-repeat left top; }    

.standard {
  @include container; 
  @include susy-grid-background; /* Susy */
```

and in my Haml:

```
%body.standard
```

Whatever I've tried the grid always shows 12 columns. Would anyone be kind enough as to point me in the direction I need to go to get this debug tool to work?

susy (1.0.rc.1)
compass (0.13.alpha.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$total-cols` should be called `$total-columns`. The name of that variable changed in 1.0. The default setting is 12 columns, and you are not actually overriding that anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

If you have some breakpoints, you also need to address these directly in order to change the number of columns `$susy-grid-background` shows:

```
.page {
  @include container ($total-columns, $break1, $break2);

  @include susy-grid-background;

  @include at-breakpoint($break1)  {
    @include susy-grid-background;
  }
  @include at-breakpoint($break2)  {
    @include susy-grid-background;    
  }
}
```